# A scatter plot with given labels and x- and y- axis values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I'm trying to create a scatter-plot with:

- Labels in column A
- X-axis values in column B
- Y-axis values in column C

Both column B and C have non-integer values.

I've tried fiddling with all the advanced options, but I'm not having much luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A point plot in which individual points are labeled is called a *bubble plot*:

[image: bubble plot]

The structure of input data is exactly what you stated: labels in the first column, x coordinates in the second, y coordinates in the third

```
Mercury  1.2     5.3
Venus    2.3     6.7
Earth    3.4     3
Mars     2.1     1.6
```

Optionally, one can have a 4th column for categories (represented by colors) and 5th for bubble sizes. Reference: [chart types](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190718?hl=en).